# Is there a SSH (remote) command history

Tags: ssh

I have a script which runs a bunch of remote SSH commands. This list of commands grew large so I want to pull them out, but of course there are many maskings in the command (e.g. "$USER" as "\$USER"), sometimes in more than one shell depth the maskings occur, making it a longer approach to pull all out by hand.

So I asked myself: is there some sort of SSH (or sshpass) command history (e.g. similar to .bash_history), where I can simply pull out what has been executed? (logging on local host would be the best, installing something on foreign host the worst)

Comment: no. Bash history locally is your only chance.

Comment: There might be an answer for you in [http://serverfault.com/questions/559658/log-commands-executed-over-ssh]

Comment: Thx, but does not look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in my case it's just as simple as starting the program `script` on the local host to log all input and output of the console, then start the SSH using script…